# Error comparing dates in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing a sql query where I need to convert varchar column value to date and use it in where clause.

Following is the query that I am trying;

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT t1.record_id,
    t1.column_name,
    t1.value,
    t1.row_index,
    t1.start_date,
    t1.end_date,
    t2.value AS val
   FROM sf_monthly_fin_exp t1,
    sf_monthly_fin_exp t2
  WHERE t1.row_index         = t2.row_index
  AND t1.generated_report_id = t2.generated_report_id
  AND t1.generated_report_id =11700
  AND t2.column_name         = 'Date'
  AND t2.value              <> 'Total'
  AND t1.column_name = 'xyz'
  ORDER BY t1.row_index
  )
WHERE TO_DATE(val, 'dd/mm/YYYY') = TO_DATE('05/01/2014', 'dd/mm/YYYY');
```

I am converting the value to date type while comparing but it is giving me following error;

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 - a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was       expected.
```

What am I doing wrong in the query, any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: But why do you store dates in a varchar column?

Comment: Provide sample data. And you should fix your design first. Storing dates as strings is a pretty bad design. Use appropriate data types.

Comment: this table is kind of key value pair, it stores many kind of values one of the is Date, where the column name is Date and value is some date value stored as varcher.

Comment: @varun Provide the sample data as create and insert statements. How is the data in `val` look like?

Comment: Why there is the need of converting to date first of all when you know that there are other values also apart from date? Why not you do simple string search as `WHERE val = '05/01/2014';`

Comment: Actually i need to search in date range using between.

Answer (score 0):

You try convert "t2.value" to date. Probably you would like convert "t1.value":

```
WHERE TO_DATE(value, 'dd/mm/YYYY') = TO_DATE('05/01/2014', 'dd/mm/YYYY');
```